# cinnamon yields black background in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, cinnamon, debugging, 15.10

I just installed U15.10. The *only* thing I did was

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Then I logged off, logged in with cinnamon, and I get a black background, terminal has white background, some icons are missing, right click not working on the background.

I could get the icons with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full
```

The other issues could apparently be related to `nemo` and `nautilus` but that's beyond my knowledge;

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons
gsettings get org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons
```

as suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2158464), both return `true`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Edit** As suggested by Raphael, I tried to change the icons, using

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

I logged out and in (without rebooting), but the icons did not change.

Comment: If you want the desktop icons then set the gsettings to false.

Comment: As for icons would you mind installing a new icon theme such as numix from their ppa and post if that icon pack brings back all your icons.

Comment: @Raphael In fact, I'm not sure if you understood that I managed to get the icons back. Now that I install numix I can also choose them from the Theme menu. I'm not sure how this helps though.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. I got the background working with `sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment`, but some icons remain looking weird. I'll try to install numix tomorrow

Comment: @LPrc I don't know why, but apparently the problem is gone for me: I haven't noticed any high-CPU usage due to cinnamon for more than a month. But I am still interested in a solution though. Good luck.

Comment: I didn't have to install numix. I just installed `gnome-icon-theme-full` and cinnamon works fine (with cinnamon-desktop-environment, not with cinnamon only)

Answer (score 3):

You said

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons
gsettings get org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons
```

> both returned true

but the link you've given doesn't suggest that and It's wrong actually. Either one of them should be true. If you want Nemo to control your desktop, you should use

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

Your [suggested link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2158464) says -

> I don't think both keys should be true.
>   Like it says here: http://www.fandigital.com/2013/01/set-nemo-default-file-manager-ubuntu.html